# Double for loop list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to do following operation using list comprehensions:

```
Input: [['hello ', 'world '],['foo ',' bar']]
Output: [['hello', 'world'], ['foo', 'bar']]
```

Here is how one can do it without list comprehensions:

```
a = [['hello ', 'world '],['foo ',' bar']]
b = []

for i in a:
   temp = []
   for j in i:
      temp.append( j.strip() )
      b.append( temp )

print(b)
#[['hello', 'world'], ['foo', 'bar']]
```

How can I do it using list comprehensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = [['hello ', 'world '],['foo ',' bar']]
b = [[s.strip() for s in l] for l in a]
print(b)
# [['hello', 'world'], ['foo', 'bar']]
```

Comment: I will accept this since this is the first answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Simply next one `list` comprehension as each element of a larger `list` comprehension:

```
>>> i = [['hello ', 'world '],['foo ',' bar']]
>>> o = [[element.strip() for element in item] for item in i]
>>> o
[['hello', 'world'], ['foo', 'bar']]
```

Or use `list()` and `map()`:

```
>>> i = [['hello ', 'world '],['foo ',' bar']]
>>> o = [list(map(str.strip, item)) for item in i]
>>> o
[['hello', 'world'], ['foo', 'bar']]
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
input = [['hello ', 'world '], ['foo ',' bar']]

output = [[item.strip() for item in pair] for pair in input]

print output


[['hello', 'world'], ['foo', 'bar']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grid = [[1,1,0],[0,1,0],[1,0,1]]
visited_arr = [[False for elm in i ]for i in grid]
print(visited_arr)


[[False,False, False],[False,False, False],[False,False, False]]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer].