# Python: Locate word that contains certain string in list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to locate words that contains certain string inside a list of lists in python, for example: If I have a list of tuples like:

```
the_list = [
    ('Had denoting properly @T-jointure you occasion directly raillery'), 
    ('. In said to of poor full be post face snug. Introduced imprudence'),
    ('see say @T-unpleasing devonshire acceptance son.'),
    ('Exeter longer @T-wisdom gay nor design age.', 'Am weather to entered norland'),
    ('no in showing service. Nor repeated speaking', ' shy appetite.'),
    ('Excited it hastily an pasture @T-it observe.', 'Snug @T-hand how dare here too.')
    ]
```

I want to find a specific string that I search for and extract a complete word that contains it, example

```
for sentence in the_list:
    for word in sentence:
        if '@T-' in word:
            print(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

wordSearch = re.compile(r'word')
for x, y in the_list:
    if wordSearch.match(x):
        print(x)
    elif wordSearch.match(y):
        print(y)
```

Comment: In this case, "x" and "y" are the strings I want to search for inside the words (like '@T-'), right?

Comment: well, your tuple is ("this", "that"), so for each iteration, x = this and y = that.  Your match will go against each item and then you only deal with the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could use list of comprehension on a flattened array of yours:

```py
from pandas.core.common import flatten

[[word for word in x.split(' ') if '@T-' in word] for x in list(flatten(the_list)) if '@T-' in x]
#[['@T-jointure'], ['@T-unpleasing'], ['@T-wisdom'], ['@T-it'], ['@T-hand']]
```

Relevant places: [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists) (specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57225427/12281892)), [Double for loop list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33249350/double-for-loop-list-comprehension).

Answer (score 0):

you would need to use re for this task

```
import re

a = re.search("@(.*?)[\s]",'Exeter longer @T-wisdom gay nor design age.')

a.group(0)
```

Note : you need to account for the Nonetype else it will throw and error

```
for name in the_list:
try:
    
    if isinstance(name,(list,tuple)):
        for name1 in name:
            result = re.search("@(.*?)[\s]",name1)
            print(result.group(0))
    else:
        
        result = re.search("@(.*?)[\s]",name)
        print(result.group(0))
    

except:
    pass
```